# Autocomplete jQuery & php problem

Tags: php, jquery

i am trying to get a list of names from MySQL table useing php and jQuery autocomplete function but i get no result.could you help plz

here is jQuery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" 
  type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function findmatch(str){
    if (str.length>0){
      $('#found').load('SelectQury.php?n='+str);
    }
  }//fun
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="textfield" autocomplete="off"    
     onkeyup="findmatch(this.value);"/>
    <div id="found" >non found</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

php code

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
    $s=$_POST['text'];

$query="SELECT FROM student WHERE name LIKE '$s%'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die ('Wrong query : ' . mysql_error() );
$string='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $string.= $row['name'];
}
echo $string;
}else{
  echo 'wrong GET keywoord';

}//ifisset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

```
1. you are sending the value as "GET" method `?n=` and accessing in the PHP code as `$_POST`
2. the passed variable is `n` and not `text`
3. error in mysql query
```

Use the following PHP code:

```
if(isset($_GETT['n'])){
   $s=$_GET['n'];

    $query="SELECT * FROM student WHERE name LIKE '$s%'";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die ('Wrong query : ' . mysql_error() );
    $string='';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $string.= $row['name'];
    }
      echo $string;
  }else{
     echo 'wrong GET keywoord';

}
```

Comment: thanks now i get this error msg: Wrong query : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM student WHERE name LIKE a%' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the server function to return the HTML for a list rather than a single string that is the concatenation of the all the student names. Have you used a tool like fiddler to check what is being sent and returned from the server?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you could use `$.getJSON` for simplicity that jQuery can parse quickly than using the `.load` function.

Since you're using `post` it can be done this way with jQuery:

```
var inputName = $('input[name=text]').val();

$.post('SelectQury.php', { text: inputName }, function(response)
{
    var nameBuild = '';
    for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
    {
        nameBuild += '<div class="row">' + response[i].name + '</div>';
    }

    $(nameBuild).appendTo('#found');
}, 'JSON');
```

If you're using `get`, then use the `$.getJSON` by doing this:

```
var inputName = $('input[name=text]').val();

$.getJSON('SelectQury.php', { name: inputName }, function(response)
{
    var nameBuild = '';
    for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
    {
        nameBuild += '<div class="row">' + response[i].name + '</div>';
    }

    $(nameBuild).appendTo('#found');
});
```

**PHP:**

Replace $_POST as $_GET if you're using get than post

```
if(isset($_POST['text']))
{
    $s = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);

    $query = "SELECT FROM student WHERE name LIKE '$s%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Wrong query : ' . mysql_error() );

    $string = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
         $string[] = array('name' => $row['name']);
    }

    echo json_encode($string);
}
else
{
    echo 'wrong GET keywoord';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple really. JQuery does most of the hard work. The problem is getting the data from php to javascript. Then after that, you pass the data into jquery's autocomplete function

example:

```
var data = "<?php echo implode(",",$customer_list) ?>".split(",");
    $("#CUSTOMER_NAME" ).autocomplete({source: data});
```

Here is a customer_list array that is put into the javascript data array. Use jquery selector on the input field, then add autocomplete function.

Hope that helps